# Replace word between tags with the word itself

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, tags

I need to transform a string:

```
Hi, I am a [l=BANANA]
```

to:

```
Hi, I am a BANANA
```

I am not a Regex expert so I tried to adapt a few examples to my case, however nothing seemed to work properly.

Comment: What examples? Please share.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to replace `[l=...]` or just `[anything=...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with regex:

```
\[l=([^\]]+)\]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kG8iA0/1)

it match a word preceded by `l=`, within square brackets. Then you can raplece it with captured group 1 (what regex part in parathesis `([^\]]+)` captured). If there could be another sequence than `l=` you can use for example `\[\w+=(\w+)\]`, result should be the same.

Implementation in Java:

```
String test = "Hi, I am a [l=BANANA SPLIT]";
test = test.replaceAll("\\[l=([^]]+)]","$1");
System.out.println(test);
```

with output:

```
Hi, I am a BANANA SPLIT
```

Comment: It is working well, however... I need to replace also words separated by a space like [l=BANANA SPLIT] to BANANA SPLIT

Comment: @user2468425 try with `\[l=([^\]]+)\]`, it should work as long as you want everything from `=` to end of bracket